# Does changing Windows logon password automatically change service logon?

Tags: windows, windows-services

Let's say I change the password to my Windows local account on a Windows 10 Pro machine. If that local account is used to start a Windows service, does the password need to be manually updated on the service?

[image: screenshot of Azure login and local user login dialog boxes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a feature seems to me to be contrary to elementary
security practices.
I would find it a serious bug and a big security concern if
entering the user password in one context will automatically
enter it in a potentially
unlimited number of other contexts on which I have no control.

The Microsoft article
[About Service Logon Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/about-service-logon-accounts)
backs up my opinion with this text:

> Password maintenance.
> For a service that runs under a user account,
> **you** must periodically change the password and **keep the password in sync** with the password used by one or more local service control
> managers to start the service.

Another article
[Using a domain user account as a service logon account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/domain-user-accounts?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
says:

> A service instance that uses a **domain user account requires periodic administrative action to maintain the account password**. The service control manager (SCM) on the host computer of a service instance **caches the account password** for use in logging on the service. **When you change the account password, you must also update the cached password on the host computer where the service is installed**. For more information and a code example, see Changing the password on a service's user account. You could avoid the regular maintenance by leaving the password unchanged, but that would increase the likelihood of a password attack on the service account. Be aware that even though **the SCM stores the password in a secure portion of the registry**, it is nevertheless subject to attack.

This specifies that it's the SCM that stores the service password
in the registry, but the SCM is not invoked when a user changes
his password.

My answer is therefore negative : Even if for some time the
system service will seem to be running correctly after a user's
password change (because the logon token of the service
is not invalidated by the password change),
the service password will also need to be changed
in order for the SCM to store the new password.

Comment: So you're saying the direct opposite of the answer from John below. There's no link between the Windows password and Service Log On password, correct? They both have to be changed.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I say.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The Windows password change changes the service as well. I have changed my own password and services change correctly. Customers change passwords regularly and services keep working.

Comment: Yeah, but most services by default use LocalSystem and Network Service, not a local user account, correct?

Comment: The methodology  is to use Admin Credentials and so that is what allow the change to be automatic.

Comment: My current tests show that if I change the password for a local user using computer management the service won't start unless I reenter the new password in the service Log On tab

Comment: You may wish to check the Event Manager to see if something else is affecting the password change

Comment: Why did you remove the answer?   What I said works properly. Your system may not be working properly but my answer is correct.